# Postman Swift code showing different url from my normal url

Tags: python, ios, swift, django-rest-framework

I have created a filter api with more than one arguements to pass in url to filter product in my iOS application. The api is written in Python in Django rest framework. The api is working fine in postman, but when I check the code for Swift in postman is shows some complex url structure and I am confused how to apply that url string my swift code.

My serializer class:

```
class ProductOptionsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    optionproductid = ProductSerializer()
    optionattributeid = AttributeSerializer()
    optionsid = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Productoptions
        fields = ('optionproductid', 'optionattributeid', 'optionsid')
```

View:

```
class GetProductByMulipleFilter(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProductOptionsSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        query_params = self.request.query_params
        somethings = query_params.get('filters', None)

        # create an empty list for parameters to be filters by
        somethingParams = []
        serializer = self.serializer_class()
        # create the list based on the query parameters
        if somethings is not None:
            for something in somethings.split(','):
                somethingParams.append(str(something))

        if somethings is not None:
            queryset_list = Productoptions.objects.all()
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(optionattributeid__attributename__in=somethingParams)
            return queryset_list
```

url

```
url(r'^$', GetProductByMulipleFilter.as_view(), name='filters')
http://192.168.1.13:8000/api/?filters=puma,nike
```

Its working fine and showing right results. But the code in swift is showing url like:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://192.168.1.13:8000/api/?filters=puma%2Cnike")! as URL
```

My question is why the url in Swift code is not showing parameter seperated with ',' only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because request encode `,` symbol into `%2C` while it was processed. You can find more about `URL percent encoding` on [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)

> When a character from the reserved set (a "reserved character") has
>   special meaning (a "reserved purpose") in a certain context, and a URI
>   scheme says that it is necessary to use that character for some other
>   purpose, then the character must be percent-encoded. Percent-encoding
>   a reserved character involves converting the character to its
>   corresponding byte value in ASCII and then representing that value as
>   a pair of hexadecimal digits. The digits, preceded by a percent sign
>   (%) which is used as an escape character, are then used in the URI in
>   place of the reserved character. (For a non-ASCII character, it is
>   typically converted to its byte sequence in UTF-8, and then each byte
>   value is represented as above.)

Comment: Oh yes , never though about that. Thanks.

Comment: @vishwas If this answer is an answer for your question, please, remember to upvote and accept it! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
let param = "anyThing"

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://192.168.1.13:8000/api/?filters=\(param)")! as URL
```